Avoid showing terminal when executing pkg generated .exe
I packaged my node application in an .exe with pkg but when I run it with a double click or with a .bat file, the executable opens a console for the app. Is there a possibility to run the .exe without showing any console?
.bat
@echo off
start "" "%~index.exe"

No show de terminal when execute the program

Given pkg is deprecated, have you checked out one of the forks or the Node.js 21 Single Executable Applications?

It's been raised as an issue with pkg here and here. Looks like there's plenty of suggestions

@Phil I try do the executable with node, but the result is the same, when i execute my app open a terminal and no run in the background

I solved it by doing this link
